# Can I use a query result as filter or query parameter?

Tags: elasticsearch

Not sure how to best describe my problem, so be gentle :-)

I have search data for products and corressponding specifications in a multilingual environment. The specifications are all stored as simple key value pairs, and rather than storing the translation each time (because it might change overtime) for the keys I want to work with identifier keys in one index, and the translated terms in another index.

A potential scenario would therefore be as follows :

- A search is performed on a given product using a filter
- For this model all spec key-value pairs are returned
- For every key and some values the translation is returned from a different index

So let's assume I search for specs for product ABC-123, the  system would find for instance

SpecID1:color_black

SpecID7:123g

The final result should contain

- "Color":"Black"
- "Weight":"123g"

Where SpecID1 would be "Color" in the english translations index, and "Coleur" in the French translations index. So when on the UK section of my site all translations would come from the en_trans index, for France from the fr_trans section and so on.

Hope this makes some sense.

Is this possible with ES in one call? And if do, what would be the approach?

Answer (score 0):

There're four ways to manage relational data in Elasticsearch:

1. Application-side joins
2. Data denormalization
3. Nested objects
4. Parent/child relationships

For your case obvious solution is number 1 or 2. I would really recommend to prefetch all translations in a memory cache and lookup them after searching translation keys in ES.

Comment: I actually wanted to avoid to do this on the application side. It's relatively easy to achieve, but it would mean that for each key I would have to make a separate call. Hence why I was hoping to do this is one call versus doing this in potentially a lot of calls. I might be overlooking something but the latter seems less efficient.

Comment: Basically the only option is storing the list of translations instead of a key in ES. If it does not suit you, then use precached approach. ES is not a relational DB. Separate call with in-memory cache is nothing comparing to workarounds like denormalization in your case.